# SSH works except from internet via cellphone and juice app

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, ufw

Ok, this is the 3rd version of Ubuntu on exact same confuguration of hardware, wired to same network with the same internet and static IP.

The box running 16.04 has run 15(like 16 was apt-get dist-upgrade an 14 was a fresh install.

Prior to dist-upgrade I could access the box from my ssh app, juice, from internet, through router/modem etc on 14 & 15.

After dist-upgrade i can not access from my cell over the internet. LAN  logins work just fine.

Port 22 in ufw is allowed. I even disabled ufw and tried still the same "authentication failure"

The user and password are the same as both previous versions installed on exwct same setup.

Also i have multiple raspberry Pi's running wirelessly on LAN  that i CAN access from juice app on my cellphone from work.

I am a novice user at best so google has been my goto search.

Somewhere to look would be great

Thx
Bill

Comment: Have you forwarded port 22 on your router and verified that it is forwarding to the correct internal IP?

Comment: Yes, i changed nothing other the apt-get dist upgrade. Router, LAN and WAN all remained same from previous version on same system. My username and pass from previous versions 14 & 15 worked and still works LAN just not WAN

Answer (score 0):

My primary thought:

1. Able to connect internally, not externally. Verify your MASK value.

   ifconfig -a

Review the target systems interfaces file, or Network Manager configuration. Verify the following is set for your interfaces file (if used):

```
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.0 ;adjust accordingly
gateway yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy ;adjust accordingly
```

Within Network Manager, disable IPV6. And verify the correct subnet mask/gateway for your subnet.

Comment: Ip attempt to disks ipv6 within the network manager.. Will a restart be required.  As i said i can find the system and it acknowledges my username but give authentication failure.

Comment: Also i have checked ufw to see if that was the case, it is not, port 22 is allowed. Attempted with ufw enabled & disabled as well using subsequent reboots

Comment: I still get authentication failure

Comment: Update.been watching tail -f /var/log/auth.log and i see numerous attempt from 116... IP adress trying to login as root and failing.  I however do not see any attempt from my ISP IP 227... This tells me it's quite possibly my router, how it has changed from 15 to 16 is beyond me.  I will try an update my router and see where that goes as soon as I can.

Comment: This is solved.

Comment: Not exactly sure what went wrong & when,  i removed the port in router,  rebooted,  readded port exactly the same,  rebooted router. Turned wifi of on phone and stayed an ssh session from my phone,  it worked.